# How can I write code For multiple textbox leave event only once

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using this code on textbox `Leave event` to Make `first Letter` of textbox to `uppercase`,On form I have Particular textboxes for which I want to get same Functionality done ,but Is there any way so that I don't need to write same code in each textbox leave event ,How can I do this

```
private void txtAdrs2A_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtAdrs2A.Text.Length >= 1)
        txtAdrs2A.Text = txtAdrs2A.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + txtAdrs2A.Text.Substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sender` parameter instead of specifying the `TextBox` by its `Id`:

```
private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = sender as TextBox;

    if(box != null && box.Text.Length > 0)
        box.Text = box.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + box.Text.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: But How can I use this for other textboxes too ,because this is again written in Leave event

Comment: You can use the same method as event handler for more than one element. Use properties window to do that - instead of creating new one select your method from the dropdown.

Comment: I didn't got,From which property of textbox I can Select this Method?Because in events I don't find this listed

Comment: Click `events` icon on top of the window and you'll find a list of available events. There should be `Leave` within the list.

Comment: Yes It is very Nice solution ,I learned something New ,Thanks :)

Comment: It should be `var box = sender as TextBox;` if you're going to do a `null` check afterwards. Otherwise it will never be null or an `InvalidCastException` would've been thrown by that point.

Comment: @keyboardP You're totally right! I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sender`

```
    private void text_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox text = (TextBox)sender;
        if (text.Text.Length >= 1)
        {
            text.Text = text.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + text.Text.Substring(1
        }
    }
```

Then loop through all textboxes to assign the event to them

```
    foreach (TextBox t in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        t.Leave += new EventHandler(text_Leave);
    }
```